# Angular JS ng-repeat not showing up

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was having some trouble with the Angular `ng-repeat` directive. The attached is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController as me" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>
    <tr>
        <th>Test Suite Name</th>
        <th>Test Suite Key</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <th>Total Tests</th>
        <th>Passed</th>
        <th>Failed</th>
        <th>Quarantined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in myData">
        <th>{{data.name}}</th>
        <th>{{data.plan_key}}</th>
        <th>{{data.start_date}}</th>
        <th>{{data.start_time}}</th>
        <th>{{data.end_time}}</th>
        <th>{{data.total_test}}</th>
        <th>{{data.test_passed}}</th>
        <th>{{data.test_failed}}</th>
        <th>{{data.test_quarantined}}</th>
    </tr>
    <h1>Data from server: {{myData[0].name}}</h1>
  </div>

  <script>
    var $received_data;

    var test = angular.module("myapp", []);
       //     .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        //          $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        //          delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
         //      }
         //    ])
        test.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {

                var responsePromise = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/home");

                responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("ok")
                    $scope.myData = data.result;
                    //$scope.received_data = data.reault;
                });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("error?");
                });
            }


        } );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

So basically it gets a list of JSON and I want it to be printed in table form.
I am trying to do it with ng-repeat with `tr ng-repeat="data in myData"`  but it somehow didn't show up.

However, the `<h1>Data from server: {{myData[0].name}}</h1>` did get printed out correctly.

I am new to AngularJS so I suppose it must be something really stupid mistake that I have made.

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest first formatting it so you're using proper table html

Comment: Try putting your data into an array, also the doClick might be conflicting. ng-repeat may be trying to do something with this.

Also you myData.doClick is being overwritten by your http response.

Id suggest you make something like this `$scope.testSuite= {get: ..http.., data: [] }`

Comment: Your table tag is missing ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple problems here.

**1** your HTML structure should be reworked. Ideally it should look like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in myData.result">
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.start_date}}</td>
      <td>{{data.start_time}}</td>
      <td>{{data.end_time}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**2** This refers to @blowsies comment. You are using the same `$scope.myData` to handle the function & the data. Which is fine, but you're missing a level of nesting. Currently you have a `$scope.myData.doClick()` which loads the data from the server. And then you assign it at `$scope.myData` which is most likely having a problem. Instead, assign it to $scope.myData.result` and change your HTML accordingly.

**[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9iyJ2ybxYl11QaAZMSQU?p=preview)**